# PHP DOMDocument saveHTML Adds Charachter

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to use DOMDocument and when I saved the HTML, it seems to be adding extra special charachters on the output.

```
$output = '<div>©Deneme</div>';

$html = new DOMDocument("1.1");
$html->loadHTML($output);

echo $html->saveHTML();
```

The output is

```
<div>Â©Deneme</div>
```

Why does the output has "Â"? I couldn't figure it out.

Thank you,

Comment: Hate to close without helping, sooo https://3v4l.org/jaScd

Comment: I didn't know I should have searched for utf-8 encoding. Thank you.